# Bucle infinito de Javascript para una pagina web

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Cómo crear un bucle infinito en javascript que permita al navegador cargar

Comment: Es tan fácil como hacerlo.

Comment: Bienvenido. A algunos que participan por primera vez en este sitio les parece desconcertante el que su primera pregunta reciba votos negativos en particular cuando no ha seguido el [tour] ni consultado [ask]. No te desanimes. Puedes eliminar tu pregunta para empezar de cero y publicar una nueva o bien intentar empezar por responder preguntas de otros.

Comment: Si pero los navegadores van a detectar que tu script está bloqueado y van a mandar una alerta al usuario con la opción de detener el script.

Comment: @Trauma Pues no, no es tan fácil. [Lo he hecho](http://i.imgur.com/bavC1JF.png) y el resultado no me convence. Sospecho que hay más detalles para hacer un bucle `while(true)` que los que un novato como yo pueda descubrir solo probando a hacerlo. WTFChamp, no te desanimes por los votos negativos, yo te he votado positivo porque la pregunta es apropiada e incluye el código relevante. Además de que le interesa a mucha gente, como demuestran las muchas respuestas recibidas. A esa gente a la que le interesa le animo a votar positivo a esta pregunta.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Si es tan fácil; basta con hacerlo. Dado que javascript está basado en eventos, y los eventos no se procesan mientras no finalices toda la parte secuencial del código, el navegador se queja de que se le llena la cola y no encuentra un *hueco* para procesarlos. Eso está *relacionado* con el bucle, pero no te impide hacerlo. El bucle funciona. Funciona tan bien, que no deja al navegador responder :-)

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos De todas formas, lo que quería indicar con mi comentario es que **lo hiciera**, y después de hacerlo, preguntar por lo que fuera. No niego que existan situaciones *de riesgo* en las que interese preguntar primero, pero en esta pregunta en cuestión, creo que no se dan dichas circunstancias :-)

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios y votos, siempre sirven de orientación y agradezco a @AsierVillanueva por su respuesta! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sí, por supuesto que se puede. En el `while` puedes poner cualquier expresión válida de javascript, también una constante como `true`:

```js
var cont=0;
while(true){
  console.log(cont++);
  if (cont>10) { break; }
}
```

Comment: Gracias tu respuesta me sirve de ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

```
While (condicion) {
 Codigo que se va a ejecutar
}
```

El codigo se ejecutara, cuando se cumpla la condición.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp